# Firebase Admin SDK to download/retrieve files on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-admin

I'm trying to download some images that I have uploaded to my Google Cloud Storage (aka into buckets). I'm unable to use the .ref() method on any of my `const storage` or `const bucket` because they are part of the admin SDK. The admin.storage has only the method .bucket() (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage).

I'm able to access the buckets.
bucket.getFiles() works, and the result comes out to be an Array of Files objects with a ton of metadata (like file name, bucket owner, etc.). How can I get my images from the cloud storage and insert them into html objects?

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./randomDB-f12d3-admin-correctly-working.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://randomDB-f12d3.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "randomDB-f12d3.appspot.com"
});

const gcs  = require("@google-cloud/storage");
gcs.projectId = "randomDB-f12d3";
gcs.keyFilename = "randomDB-f12d3-firebase-admin-correctly-working.json";﻿

exports.getFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  
  cors(req, res, () => {
    if (req.method !== "GET") {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: "Not allowed"
      });
    }

    const storage = admin.storage();
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    bucket.getFiles().then((result)=>{
      
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: You can use .file() to get a specific file. See the [GCS client API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/File) as well as the [Firebase samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js) for examples

Answer (score 8):

The Admin SDK for Cloud Storage is just a wrapper around the [@google-cloud/storage module](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/).  When you call `admin.storage()`, what you're getting back is a [Storage](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Storage) object from that library.  With `admin.storage().bucket()`, you're getting the default storage [Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket) for your project.  From there, you should use [`file()`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#file) to create a reference to files in that bucket and [download](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download) them as needed.

Comment: I'm trying to call storage.ref() to make a reference to the file I want to download. However, I'm getting an error saying that .ref() is not a method for storage. Why is this happening? I'm not able to do anything with the storage object...

Comment: That's because there is no ref() with the Cloud Storage API.  Please read my answer again, and click the links to view the API documentatio.

Comment: Answer has broken links in it. Side to that it does not answer the question.

Comment: The "download as needed" part is where this answer comes up short. You should elaborate as it is the core part of the question.