# How to retrieve images from firebase storage according to the category of the images(ex Cars,abstract)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to know how to retrieve images from the firebase storage for my wallpaper app which has been manually uploaded by me to the firebase storage. I want the images from the firebase storage to display according to the category of the images like cars, abstract,3D.

I am talking about the app for ios.

I tried some of the code which i got it online, but it is not displaying the images according to the category it is getting shuffled.
I just want help how to retrieve the images from the firebase storgae and display according to the category of the images.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage has no ways to list or query the files. If you want your application to show a number of files, you'll have to get the paths/URLs for those files from somewhere else.

Typically developers store either the file paths, or the download URLs, in a database (such as Firebase's Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore), with the associated metadata of that file. They can then query the information in that database from their app to determine the paths/URLs of the files to display.

Alternatively you can use one of the server-side SDKs for Cloud Storage (such as the Node.js one that is included in the Firebase Admin SDK), to get a list of files.

Also see:

- [How to get a list of all files in Cloud Storage in a Firebase app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335102/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-files-in-cloud-storage-in-a-firebase-app/37337436)
- [Firebase Admin SDK to download/retrieve files on Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599481/firebase-admin-sdk-to-download-retrieve-files-on-google-cloud-storage)
- [Delete folder in Google Cloud Storage using nodejs gcloud api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597802/delete-folder-in-google-cloud-storage-using-nodejs-gcloud-api)